# With some known probability,set the value of a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, social-networking, probability

EDIT:If anyone downvotes this question,kindly leave a comment explaining why.
I am implementing a certain algorithm in Java called the Biased Voter Model which models the opinion dynamics of social network users. 
Here there is a particular step which requires me to:

```
With probability pi , set x = q1 ; else with probability pi , set x = q2,and so on.

If the above step did not set x, then:
– With probability αi , set x = q0 ; and
– With probability 1 − αi set x = q, where
  q ∈ [q0 , q ∗ ] is chosen uniformly at random.
```

Where, pi and αi are randomly chosen and is constant throughout. `q1,q2...qn` are known values. 'x' is what I need to set. And also q* is the q(i) which is has the smallest distance(closest) to q0.[Note:q0 is not a part of the array and is also known]
 But what I'm not sure of is what does the phrase **"With probability pi set x=q1"** ?
I have tried implementing it this way:

```
        pi=(double)Math.round(Math.random()*10)/10;//sets a random number approximated to one decimal place

        while(index<n){
        double j=(double)Math.round(Math.random()*10)/10;
        if(j>pi){
            index++; 
        }
        else{
            x=q[index];
                    break;
        }
         }
```

However this is for the 1st part only. `q[]` contains `q1,q2...qn` and for each index I'm generating a random number `j` and if it's greater than `pi` I ignore that index and move on to the next.

For the second part I check `j` with αi.(The following is just a pseudocode and I haven't written everything here)

```
double j=(double)Math.round(Math.random()*10)/10;
if(j<αi)
  {
   temp1=q0;
  }
 double j=(double)Math.round(Math.random()*10)/10;
  //randomly generate 'k' which takes on a value of either 0 or 1
 if(j<(1-αi){
   if(k==0)
        temp2=q0;

     else if(k==1)
              temp2=q*;

     }
   if(temp1==temp2)
        x=q0;
   else
         x=q*
```

I know this implementation is not completely correctly. Where am I logically going wrong? And what does the phrase **"With probability pi set x=q1"** actually mean?
For further reference,check [this](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~kamesh/opinion_model.pdf) (page 7 section 5).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overthinking it.

1. At start of program choose `pi` at random between 0 and 1, because `pi` is a probability.

   ```
    Random random = new Random();
    double pi = random.nextDouble(); // Choose a number between 0 and 1.
   ```
2. With probability `pi` set `x=q1`. Choose another random number between 0 and 1. If that number is less than `pi`, then set `x = q1`. Otherwise, set `x = q`. This is correct because the probability of a random number chosen uniformly between 0 and 1 being less than `pi` is exactly equal to `pi`.

   ```
   double t = random.nextDouble();
   if (t < pi) x = q1;
   else x = q;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but firstly,for pi we have to set x=q1 or q2 or... qn,that's just the first part. The first part isn't really where I'm stuck,what I need to know is if I'm on the right track with the second part.